# Python(Linked List) - Attribute Error

Tags: python, linked-list

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, init_data):
        self.data = init_data
        self.next = None

    def get_data(self):
        return self.data

    def get_next(self):
        return self.next

    def set_data(self, new_data):
        self.data = new_data

    def set_next(self, new_next):
        self.next = new_next

    def __str__(self):
        return self.data

class LinkedListIterator:
    def __init__( self, head):
        self.current = head

    def __next__( self ):
        if self.current != None:
            item = self.current.get_data()
            self.current = self.current.get_next()
            return item
        else :
            raise StopIteration

class UnorderedList:

    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def add(self, item): #add to the beginning of the list
        new_node = Node(item)
        new_node.set_next(self.head)
        self.head = new_node

    def size(self):
        current = self.head
        count = 0
        while current != None:
            count = count + 1
            current = current.get_next()
        return count

    def is_empty(self):
        return self.head == None

    def search(self,item):
        current = self.head
        while current != None:
            if current.get_data() == item:
                return True
            else:
                current = current.get_next()
        return False

    def remove(self, item):
        #Assumes the item is in the linked list
        current = self.head
        previous = None
        found = False
        while not found:
            if current.get_data() == item:
                found = True
            else:
                previous = current
                current = current.get_next()
        if previous == None:
            self.head = current.get_next() #remove the first node
        else:
            previous.set_next(current.get_next())


#Iterator

    def __iter__(self):
        return LinkedListIterator(self.head)

    def get(self,pos):
        current = self.head
        for i in range(0, pos):
            current = current.next
        return(current.data)
```

For some reason, whenever i run the test case:

```
my_list = UnorderedList()
for x in [3,5,4,6,7,8]:
    my_list.add(x)
print(my_list.get(6))
```

I always run into the "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'data'"

I found that to be very weird, i thought i am allowed to return like that in python? i can't figure out what the error is. would someone care to help me?

Comment: What is your question? Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: sorry, my bad. with all the code i forgot to include the question. my question is that, what do i do to fix my code? but i can fix the code on my own aswell. what concerns me most is the error i get saying that there is no "set_next" attribute??

Comment: If you can fix the code on your own, why aren't you doing that? If you want help here, give a minimal example and full error traceback, along with what you've tried so far to fix it.

Comment: i apologize for being unclear, my issue is that my code will not sort(smallest to biggest). so am i making a mistake somewhere where it is not doing that?

Comment: Finding that *"somewhere"* is **your job**, see e.g. http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/